# Entity Framework 6 - Entity classes get deleted when updating edmx, why is that? and what can I do to stop it?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

When updating the entity framework diagram using the EDMX Designer, sometimes the entities under the model.TT file get deleted and I then have to undo the changes in Source Control.

What is the reason for this and what can I do to stop this from happening?

Comment: You can stop using EDMX Designer and start using POCO (Code-First) approach. AFAIK EDMX Designer is being deprecated in EF 7 anyway.

Comment: Every time you save changes in the EDMX it regenerates the classes. If you dont delete and re-add the class in the designer, then it shouldnt be regenerated.

Comment: Yeah, someone mentioned this in a previous question I asked about EF, but unfortunately I don't have control over what I am using at work. I am sure we will cross that bridge when we come to it. But I will be using Code-First on all my personal and future projects. Cheers

Comment: @br4d.net All I do is right click a blank space on the diagram and click update. Then save once it has done. So I don't delete or add anything. I then follow the advice someone else put on another thread about opening the TT file and save and it should regenerate the classes but it doens't.

Comment: Happened to me sometimes when I accidentally used a different DB connection (particularly with Oracle provider) because EF would then be unable to find the selected tables and assume there were none selected, which led to entities being removed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem one year ago. As far as I know, it's a bug that happens when you have some strange/redundant relationship in your database. Entity Framework loses its mind while updating the classes.

Delete your model, and create it without the last table you created. If this does not work, try to re-create with just a few tables ... keep updating the table by table until you find the one that is causing the problem.

Keep in mind that Database-first model (with EDMX) is "practically deprecated", EF 7 does not support it anymore. More information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/21/ef7-what-does-code-first-only-really-mean.aspx

Hope it helps!

Comment: This actually worked. I had an issue with a table/class a colleague had added. Removed that table. Did the update and it all worked. Cheers. Also, stuck using DB-first as I have no control over that. I will be using code-first in personal and future projects. Cheers.

Comment: You are welcome mate! Try to re-create that table, improving the relationship logic, if everything is correct, EF should accept it as well

Comment: The link in the answer above is a dead link.  The only approach that I have found is to (1). Create a new project folder (2) Add a new "ADO .NET Entity Data Model" to the newly created folder. (3) Replace the POCO classes and context with files from your newly created folder. (4) Delete the newly created folder. I have had no luck at all with EDMX or migrations for EF6. A robust  EDMX design tool would be useful. The problem is it is put out to the open-source community where no one is responsible because everyone is responsible.